# How to publish specific package in lerna using CICD configuration

Tags: npm, version, publish, monorepo, lerna

I have a monorepo created in private registry. It is used by various developers for creating individual components inside packages folder. The CICD pipeline is setup to publish the packages once committed to develop branch. Each week a new component is created inside packages registry and should be published as initial version.

The lerna.json is been configured as follows for independent versioning.

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

Initially all the packages has version mentioned as **1.0.1-alpha.0** during merging. When the lerna publish is done, the packages are published as **1.0.1** but still the develop branch has 1.0.1-alpha.0 in the repository.

When the next changes are done in any of the packages and committed to develop, pipeline running while publishing is failed as the version 1.0.1 is already existing in package registry. I need to delete all the packages to publish again.

My question is if I make any changes and commit it with new version in Package1 (**1.0.2-alpha.0**), will the pipeline publish only the changed package and release new version of **1.0.2** for Package1 and **omit** the rest of the packages or **overwrite** the published version with new publish. How to achieve this from CICD pipeline. Any suggestions are welcome to solve this issue.

[Img : Project Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uHeu.png)

Below is the CICD script (gitlab-ci.yml) we use for publishing.

```
script:
    - npm install
    - npx lerna run build 
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">.npmrc
    - npx lerna publish --yes --cd-version patch --skip-git
```